# PhoneGap application quits once the camera captures the image

Tags: android, cordova

I just copied the full example shown in this link 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera
and build one application and tested it on my Samsung Galaxy SCL(android).
Once i captures the image using the cam the application is getting closed.

Comment: I'm getting this with my Asus Transformer when the Camera Picture is 8M. Errors is: E/AndroidRuntime( 3926): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: I am not getting any error on my mobile and in development enviorment. The funny thing is that sometimes it works fine. I am seriously doubting that this issues is asssociated with phonegap 1.7

Comment: It started working fine when i used phonegap 1.5. But still no luck with phonegap 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a DestinationType of DATA_URL or FILE_URI? It is recommended to use FILE_URI and then use the File object to access the file. DATA_URL returns a Base64 encoded image which can cause out of memory errors.

Comment: I don't have the code with me now. I used it on another project. I think if you have a look at the PhoneGap API doc for File it shows an example of how to access the file.